# Memory Leak, SignalR in realtime webapplication

Tags: json, memory-leaks

My application connects to a SignalR-hub, and it receives about 15 json-files per minute. For every json-file with a geolocation, a marker gets placed on a sphere in the 3D WebGL-scene, and gets stored in an object {}. When the objectlist reaches 100 items, the application deletes the first item in the objectlist, and deletes the corresponding marker from the scene.

But still, there is a huge memory leak, and when I hit about 200 events, the application crash. 
Are the json-files being stored somewhere, and are causing the memory leak?

Answer (score 0):

Though this is not the solution, but I will suggest you to use Ants Profiler to see if there is any memory leak issues in your application.

I will suggest you to derefernce all the listitem in the generic list after it is no use. This is the major cause of memory leaking. 
Beware of concatenating strings, use stringbuilder as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same issue.  I had no memory leaks before implementing signalr and now have a fairly significant one.  I can disable the signalr in my app and the leak goes away.  I'm on version 2.2.0 of signalr (the most current version from Nuget.  The only thing that could be hanging up in memory from my code point of view is the event handler.  At least that's the only thing I'm creating on the client side.